Multiple calls to langchain LLM model
I have implemented a FastAPI for langchain using langserve as this:
from fastapi import FastAPI
import time
from langchain_community.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langserve import add_routes
import uvicorn



print("Loading llm ...")
config = {'gpu_layers':40}

orca_model_path = "./models/orca-2-vb_Q4_K_M/orca-2-7b.Q4_K_M.gguf"

model_path = orca_model_path

llm = CTransformers(model=model_path, model_type="orca", config=config)

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template="""
### Instruction:
Answer my question based on your knowledge
Question: {question}

### Response:
""",
    input_variables=["question"]
)

print("building chain ...")
# Step 5: Create the QA chain
qa_chain = prompt | llm

app = FastAPI(title="Lngchain Server", version="1.0", description="Test for FastAPI of langchain")

add_routes(app, qa_chain, path="/qa")

if __name__=="__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
    


So as you can see I have a local pre-trained orca-2-7b.Q4_K_M model.
When I run it, I get my server working fine. Now I have another script which sends a request to this server like this:
import requests

question = "What is the capital of Iran?"
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/qa/invoke", json={'input': {'question': question}})
print(response.json()["output"])


Which works perfectly fine.
Now, my issue is when I try to submit multiple requests at the same time using threadpool like this:
import requests
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def answer_question(question):
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/qa/invoke", json={'input': {'question': question}})
    return response.json()["output"]

questions = ["What is capital of iran?", "what is square root of 5?", "what is 2 + 3?"]

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Submit all questions to the executor
    future_to_question = {executor.submit(answer_question, q): q for q in questions}
    start = time.time()
    for future in as_completed(future_to_question):
        question = future_to_question[future]
        try:
            response = future.result()
            print(f"Question: {question}\nResponse: {response}\n")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing question '{question}': {e}")
    end = time.time()

    print(f"Duration is {end - start:.2f}")


but what I get is garbled or nonsensical responses like this:
Question: What is capital of iran?
Response: The root5 ir number means be a. be the 225

Question: what is 2 + 3?
Response: 2 square  anational which cannot as fraction can as decimal.55...:

Question: what is square root of 5?
Response: The of isr, it expressed simple It represented repeating2522
 )
: )

Duration is 3.91

I wonder how can I have my server capable of answering multiple requests using local LLM model.
